# Singular point which is regular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am reading Silverman's Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves. In the context of schemes, a point is defined to be *regular or non-singular* if its tangent space has dimension equal to the Krull dimension of its local ring. Then there's this example, which **implies the existence of singular points which are regular:**

[image]

Are singular points not supposed to be non-regular by definition? This seems contradictory to me.

[EDIT]
I suppose the use of 'singular' here refers to the special fibre but not to the whole scheme, which could be non-singular, i.e: a model for the curve.

Comment: The example is not saying the bold statement at all. A regular (or non-singular) point is one at which the local ring is regular. A singular point is the opposite.

Comment: @CraniumClamp It starts from the assumption $a \equiv 0$ mod $\pi$, that is, a singular point. And then it shows that in the case $a \not\equiv 0$ mod $\pi^2$ this singular point is indeed regular. Thats what confuses me. Is it a singular point of the special fibre or a singular point of the scheme? How do I tell which one?

Comment: The point (0,0,1) is regular as a point of the whole scheme.